# MouseUp event not firing when window normalized, only on maximized window

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mouseevent

As the title says...

I got a rectangle that servers as the title bar for my custom window. I want to add a handler to a mouseUp event on said rectangle. I did... But the event only ever fires when the window is maximized and never when normalized.

I have tried attaching the handler shown to rectangle.MouseUp, rectangle.MouseLeftButtonUp and rectangle.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp. With MouseUp and PreviewMouseUp, right button fires the event while left does not.

```cs
private void rctHeader_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    mRestoreIfMove = false;

    POINT lMousePosition;

    if (GetCursorPos(out lMousePosition) && lMousePosition.Y <= 10
        && WindowState != WindowState.Maximized)
    {
        WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    }
}
```

I have a breakpoint on mRestoreIfMove line and it only gets hit in a maximized window on mouseUp. Clicking the mouse does nothing on the normalized window.

Comment: Could you give some XAML code for a minimal working example? I am not able to reproduce the behavior you are observing.

Comment: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)."_

Comment: I was also not able to make a minimal example, I finaly solved it while experimenting with the example, though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

MouseDown handler called DragMove(); at the end. For some reason, after DragMove, the mouseUp event does not fire.

Sorry, I should have included the mouseUp event code aswell.